# Заставить set сортироваться по убыванию

Tags: c++, stl

Как известно, `set` - множество в С++, которое отсортировано по возрастанию. Мне известно, что можно сделать так, чтобы `set` был отсортирован по убыванию. Одним словом цель - добиться, чтобы `set` сортировался по убыванию. Кто знает, как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользоваться готовым средством - заменить `less` на `greater`, типа

```
set<int,greater<int>> s { 2,5,8,1,4,9};
for(auto i: s) cout << i << endl;
```

`set` - не "*множество в с++ которое отсортировано по возрастанию*", оно сортируется так, как ему указывают. По умолчанию - с помощью компаратора `less<>`. А так - сортируйте, как хотите.

Answer (score 4):

Контейнер `std::set` всегда отсортирован "по возрастанию". Вы можете повлиять лишь на то, что такой контейнер считает "возрастанием".

Каким образом будет упорядочен `std::set` определяется предикатом сравнения элементов, тип которого является вторым параметром шаблона `std::set` и значение которого является параметром конструктора `std::set`. По умолчанию в качестве предиката сравнения используется `std::less`. Стандартная реализация `std::less` внутри себя выполняет сравнение путем обращения к оператору `<` для сравниваемых элементов.

Это дает вам три возможных "точки входа" в механизм сравнения, три способа воздействовать на порядок упорядочения в `std::set` и других аналогичных контейнерах:

1. Использовать другой предикат сравнения в качестве параметра `std::set`

   ```
   #include <set>
   #include <iostream>

   struct MyType
   {
     int i;
     friend bool operator <(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
       { return lhs.i < rhs.i; };
     friend bool operator >(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
       { return lhs.i > rhs.i; };
   };

   int main()
   {
     std::set<MyType, std::greater<MyType>> my_set = 
       { { 2 }, { 8 }, { 5 }, { 4 }, { 1 }, { 3 } };
     for (auto &e : my_set)
       std::cout << e.i << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cccfbce2e58cbfc8

   Как сказано выше, *значение* этого предиката тоже учитывается контейнером - оно передается в контейнер через параметр конструктора. Хоть это и редко используемая возможность, но этот предикат можно наделить *состоянием* и решение о его поведении принимать *во время выполнения*

   ```
   #include <set>
   #include <iostream>

   struct MyType
   {
     int i;
     friend bool operator <(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
       { return lhs.i < rhs.i; };
     friend bool operator >(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
       { return lhs.i > rhs.i; };
   };

   struct MyCmp
   {
     bool ascending = true;
     bool operator ()(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs) const
     {
       return ascending ? lhs < rhs : lhs > rhs;
     }
   };

   int main()
   {
     std::set<MyType, MyCmp> 
       my_set_a({ { 2 }, { 8 }, { 5 }, { 4 }, { 1 }, { 3 } }, { true });
     for (auto &e : my_set_a)
       std::cout << e.i << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;

     std::set<MyType, MyCmp> 
       my_set_d({ { 2 }, { 8 }, { 5 }, { 4 }, { 1 }, { 3 } }, { false });
     for (auto &e : my_set_d)
       std::cout << e.i << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86f98e157467a3dd
2. Определить специализацию `std::less` для типа элемента контейнера (только если элемент `std::set` имеет  пользовательский тип)

   ```
   #include <set>
   #include <iostream>

   struct MyType
   {
     int i;
     friend bool operator <(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
       { return lhs.i < rhs.i; };
     friend bool operator >(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
       { return lhs.i > rhs.i; };
   };

   template<> struct std::less<MyType>
   {
     bool operator ()(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs) const
       { return lhs > rhs; }
   };

   int main()
   {
     std::set<MyType> my_set = { { 2 }, { 8 }, { 5 }, { 4 }, { 1 }, { 3 } };
     for (auto &e : my_set)
       std::cout << e.i << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7f508d7235e7b1
3. Определить свою версию оператора `<` для типа элемента контейнера (только если элемент `std::set` имеет пользовательский тип)

   ```
   #include <set>
   #include <iostream>

   struct MyType
   {
     int i;
     friend bool operator <(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
       { return lhs.i > rhs.i; };
   };

   int main()
   {
     std::set<MyType> my_set = { { 2 }, { 8 }, { 5 }, { 4 }, { 1 }, { 3 } };
     for (auto &e : my_set)
       std::cout << e.i << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/481288ec2ffc4e55

Второй вариант не является рекомендуемым, ибо его поведение может быть "неожиданным" для неподготовленного читателя кода. Обычно приходится выбирать между первым и третьим вариантом, в зависимости от того, является ли требуемое вами упорядочение наиболее естественным для типа элемента контейнера.

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернативу решению выше, могу предложить небольшую хитрость: чтобы set сортировался по убыванию, вы можете сделать всё числа отрицательными. Таким образом, они тоже отсортируются по убыванию.

Например:

`s.insert(x)` становится `s.insert(-x)`.

`*(s.begin())` становится `-(*(s.begin()))`

Comment: Ну такоё. Будет работать только на чисельних типах.

Comment: @ВладиславНечипорук Конечно это не полноценная альтернатива. Я просто рассказал о небольшой хитрости, которой пользовался до того, как узнал про компараторы в принципе.

Comment: ну хитрость неплохая